# Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?[]' to 'object[]'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a report with Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4, C# and the built in reporting system. I'm using a stored procedure to union and join about 13 tables I know this is me just having a brain dead moment, but as I'm trying to populate an array from a stored procedure into a ddl, I'm having issues with the following error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?[]' to 'object[]'
```

Here is the code:

```
public frm100percentQA()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox2.Visible = true;
        this.comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        List<Int32?> users = (from c in new NHISLINQ.NHISLINQDataContext().sp100PercentlQualityAssurance() where c.UserID != '0' select c.UserID).ToList();
        this.comboBox2.Items.Add("<---Select UserID--->");
        this.comboBox2.Items.Add("Select All");
        this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(users.ToArray());
        this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I know it's probably a fairly simple solution, but I'm drawing a blank at this point.  Any help?

Comment: have you tried parsing `c.UserID` to `int` in your query? The error indicates, that your UserId is not a type an integer at this point and time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't add an Int-array to an Object-array. Although you might think this should be possible, it's not. This is called Covariance.

You should first cast all values to object before you add them to the object-array. You can do that using Linq in one line:

```
this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(users.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: This worked!  I knew I had to cast it, just a brain dead moment.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably something to do with this line `this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(users.ToArray());` could you do this without using the null able `int32?` type? If so you should use a generic object and it should work.

Comment: nice catch. I guess I forgot to add what it should be if it didn't need to be the int32...oops, added it.